# Is there a way to append smth to global list in If

Tags: python-3.x, list, global-variables

My case:

```
list = []

def function(x):
   if ...: 
      list.append(x)
   else:
      list = []
```

When I try to add smth to my list python:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list' referenced before assignment
```

I use python 3, in python 2 I don't have any problems

I've already seen that it's possible when we use variables. We change them, but what about lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list = []

def function(x):
   if x==1: 
      list.append(x)
   else:
      list[:] = []

function(1)
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The work around for the above problem is

```
list = []

def function(x):
    if True:
        global list
        list.append(x)
    else:
        list = []

function(12)
print(list)
```

The error is because you haven't mention which list, so list has to mentioned in the function with keyword global and then we can use it.
PS The True is just for easiness and do not use keywords as variable names.